# Special chars in Angular package.json

Tags: angular, package.json

I'm new to Angular, and I can see some special characters in "package.json" file next to each library version. Some are start with "^" ( "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.5" ) and some are with "~" ("@types/node": "~6.0.60"). Why we are using and what is the different ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

In simple words

Suppose you want to install package "abc"

Versions of "abc" package are

1.0.0

1.0.1

1.0.2

2.0.0

2.0.1

If you write this =>

~1.0.0 then It will pick latest version of 1.0.x series

> ~1.0.0 = ~1.0.2

If you write this =>

^1.0.0 then It will pick recent version of "abc" package

> ^1.0.0 = 2.0.1